# Check if value exists in JavaScript array

Tags: javascript

I have the following code snippet.

```
$scope.functionName = function(id) {
  var flag = true;
  var numbers = [1, 3, 30];

  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (id == numbers[i]) {
      flag = false;
    } else {
      flag = true;
    }
  }
  if (flag == true) {
    console.log("this is true");
  }
  if (flag == false) {
    console.log("this is true");
  }

}
```

What I want to perform is, if the input value is in the array, `flag` value should be `false` and if not it should be `true`. But, in this code snippet although flow goes inside the for loop after that it doesn't go to any of the if conditions. After entering the for loop it directly outputs "this is true". `flag` is always being true.

Comment: Why are you using `"true"` and `"false"` instead of `true` and `false`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that @jonrsharpe. Even though I changed flag to boolean still flow is not going inside comparing if condition.

Comment: try something shorter, like `$scope.functionName = function(id){ return [1,3,30].includes(id)}`

Comment: Both `console.log` statements say "this is true".

Answer (score 2):

here is a cleaner approach at what you are trying to achieve

```
checkIfNumberIsInArray = function(number, arr) {
  return arr.includes(number)
}

console.log(checkIfNumberIsInArray(1, [1,2,3,4,5])) // true
console.log(checkIfNumberIsInArray(6, [1,2,3,4,5])) // false
```

See [MDN JavaScript Reference - array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Answer (score 0):

Add a [break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) statement when your value equal to a value in array.

```
 $scope.functionName = function(id) {
      var flag = true;
      var numbers = [1, 3, 30];

      for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if (id == numbers[i]) {
          flag = false;
          break;
        } 
      }
      if (flag == true) {
        console.log("this is true");
      }
      if (flag == false) {
        console.log("this is false");
      }

    }
```

Comment: The `else` clause is a waste of time.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to loop the array, just use indexOf. Also try to use number type for numbers, and boolean type for booleans, you are using string for both

```
$scope.functionName = function(id)
{
    var numbers = [1, 3, 30];

    var flag = numbers.indexOf(parseInt(id, 10)) > -1;  // Convert to number just in case

    if(flag === true)
    {
        console.log("this is true");
    }
    if(flag === false)
    {
        console.log("this is true");
    }
}
```